# Xarray: Error when using `data` keyword argument: DataSet.copy() got an unexpected keyword argument 'data'

Tags: python-xarray

I am making a copy of a DataSet using [xarray.DataSet.copy()](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.copy.html), providing an array to be used as the data for a new variable, like so:

```
ds_new = ds_original.copy(data={'new_var': data_array})
```

Although `data` is shown as the argument to use for this in the documentation I nevertheless get the following error when I execute the above:

```
TypeError: copy() got an unexpected keyword argument 'data'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably using an old version of xarray. `data` is only a valid argument for `.copy()` as of xarray v0.10.9, which was only released on September 21.

Comment: Bingo! Thanks for your help.